# In what language should we answer if the question is translated?

Tags: discussion, language

This is related to

- [What language should the questions be written in?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-language-should-the-questions-be-written-in)
- [Should we translate posts as a "community norm"?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22/should-we-translate-posts-as-a-community-norm)

---

If a question is asked in two languages (most of the time German and English), which language should we use for the answer?

A few suggestions:

- when in doubt, use English
- use the language that the first version of the question has
- answer in both languages, as long as you know them (I don't think this would be good)

Answer (score 8):

If the question was translated by the original author, i.e. the question was asked bilingually, I'd choose whichever seems more appropriate for the answer. If there's a lot of English involved due to the subject matter, it may be easier keep it all in English. All things equal, I'd lean towards German though.

Make sure there's always at least a German or English translation of your answer, should the answer be written in another language.

If the question was community-translated after the fact, answer in the original language as a courtesy to the author. If you're not confident enough to do so, answer in the language you feel comfortable with (given that's English or German) and perhaps leave a note soliciting a translation.

Answer (score 6):

I prefer German, if the question is not explicitly stated in English.
This will others help to learn German.

Answer (score 3):

Ich denke deutsche Muttersprachler sollten konsequent in deutsch antworten.

Comment: interessant! Nur in deutsch?

Comment: Tatsächlich halte ich mich selbst nicht dran, sondern passe mich der Frage an. Aber es ist ja auch schon ein wenig Zeit vergangen.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to add to the FAQ "You may state the language you prefer your answer in", plus what our usual behaviour in answering is.