# Ist es in Ordnung, englische Fragen auf Deutsch zu beantworten?

Tags: discussion

Ich habe jetzt schon öfters deutsche Antworten auf eigentlich englische Fragen gesehen, über die sich aber niemand zu wundern/beschweren schien. Wird ein gewisses Verständnis vorrausgesetzt, oder kommt das auf die Frage an? (Damit gemeint ist, inwiefern sich derjenige mit Deutsch auszukennen scheint)

Ein [Beispiel](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/44905/is-this-sentence-by-angela-merkel-grammatically-correct)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wir haben das schon mehrfach diskutiert:

- [Should the language of an answer match the language used in the question?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1048/should-the-language-of-an-answer-match-the-language-used-in-the-question)
- [I answered an English question in German, what should I do?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/732/i-answered-an-english-question-in-german-what-should-i-do)
- [What do we want to do with questions that mix languages?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/what-do-we-want-to-do-with-questions-that-mix-languages)

Wir sind darüber einig geworden, dass es sehr wünschenswert ist, eine Antwort [in der Sprache der Frage](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1049/23) zu formulieren, dass dies aber keine zwingende Regel sein soll, vor allem, weil es [vielleicht gute Ausnahmen gibt](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1050/23http://), weshalb jemand lieber auf Deutsch oder lieber auf Englisch schreibt.

Wichtig ist vor allen Dingen, dass die Antwort gut und hilfreich ist, da spielt die Sprache oft nur eine kleine Rolle.

Comment: Ich weiß nicht was Deine Sprachauffassung zum Ausdruck "sich einig sein" ist. Meine besagt, dass wir uns gerade nicht einig geworden sind.

Comment: @userunknown Mein gesunder Menschenverstand legt mir nahe, dass Deine *Sprach*auffassung von "sich einig sein" dieselbe ist wie meine; insbesondere sagt der Ausdruck *nicht* aus, dass man sich gerade *nicht* einig geworden sei. Während ihr euch in der *Sprache* einig seid, seid ihr es in der *Sache* allerdings nicht. Auf diesen Widerspruch wolltest Du wohl hinweisen.

Comment: @userunknown: die Diskussion fing damit an, dass man dich kritisiert hat, weil du eine deutsche Antwort auf eine englische Frage geschrieben hattest. Meine Antwort hier auf Meta hilft dir deshalb, weil sie sagt, dass solche Kritik ungerechtfertig ist - es ist eben gerade nicht so, dass das unerlaubt ist, sondern bei der Mehrheit der Meta-Voter durchaus akzeptiert wird.

Comment: @Takkat: Mal davon abgesehen, ob es nun mir hilft oder nicht, habe ich lediglich bestritten, dass wir uns einig darüber geworden seien, es sei wünschenswert, eine Frage in der Sprache zu beantworten, in der sie gestellt wurde. Dass es eine Mehrheit so sieht bestreite ich nicht. Eine Mehrheit von Usern die sich hier auf Meta abstimmend betätigt - in der aktuellen Frage also 3:-1 bei Deiner Anfwort, 2:-3 bei meiner.

Answer (score -1):

Es ist gängige Praxis Sprachen in der Sprache zu unterrichten, um die es sich handelt. Es verdoppelt quasi den Lerneffekt.

Zu fragen ist eher, wieso man Fragen in anderen Sprachen überhaupt zulässt. Das schränkt die Zahl derer, für die die Frage nützlich ist, ja deutlich ein.

Comment: I beg to disagree, and pretty emphatically. [1.1 billion people in the world are English users](https://www.ethnologue.com/language/eng). Total users of German: [132 Million](https://www.ethnologue.com/language/deu). Only a minority of German users do not understand English, and I assume that they are heavily underrepresented on StackExchange to the  point of non-existence. This means that on the contrary, *German* posts are only useful for a severely limited number of people.

Comment: Of the 1.1 billion English speaking users, most can’t ask a reasonable question about the German language and can’t make sense if an answer, no matter what language is used.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: Mit Sicherheit ist die englischsprachiger Benutzer kleiner als 1.1 Milliarden. Das dürfte eher der Teil der Weltbevölkerung sein, der englisch spricht oder sprechen kann. Woher ihr wissen wollt, wie hoch der Anteil derer ist, die kein Englisch sprechen, würde mich mal interessieren. Insbesondere ist dabei zu berücksichtigen, dass diese natürlich auch schnell abgeschreckt werden, wenn hier  alles auf Englisch verhandelt wird.

Comment: @gnasher729: Du kaufst ihm tatsächlich die 1.1 Mrd. User ab? :) Du müsstest Dich ja schon auf die Betrachtung der User beschränken, die eine Frage zur Deutschen Sprache haben, die auch von allgemeinem Interesse ist. Die dürften alle ein wenig Deutsch können.

Comment: I did not mean "English users of SE"; I meant "users of the English language" (as opposed to *speakers* which they may not be). While only a smallish fraction of these people use SE, the proportion is certainly even more biased towards the English using users.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: Und welche Relevanz haben User der englischen Sprache, die SE und insbesondere GL nicht nutzen? Auch verstehe ich nicht, mit welcher Proportion Du die Quote der SE-User unter den Englischusern vergleichst. More biased than what?

Comment: The proportion of English using people compared to the German speakers is probably even larger on SE than in the overall population (it is safe to assume that *everybody* here understands some English); speaking German therefore limits the audience even more severely.

Comment: Ein Vergleich mit der Allgemeinbevölkerung interessiert überhaupt nicht. Interessant ist, dass Sprachunterricht in aller Regel in der Sprache stattfindet, die erlernt werden soll, und das gilt um so mehr für ein internationales Forum. Bei Meetups in Berlin, die ich häufig besuche, habe ich oft Kontakt mit Nichtmuttersprachlern, aus Südamerika, Portugal, Spanien, Italien, Australien, USA, England, Polen, Russland, der Ukraine, Südkorea, China, Hongkong und der Türkei sowie dem ganzen arabischen Raum.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: Und ein kleiner, aber nicht unbeachtlicher Teil, spricht Deutsch besser als Englisch. Nicht die Mehrheit, aber vielleicht so ein Drittel/ein Viertel. Und ich verstehe nicht, wieso jemand, der Deutsch lernen will, auch noch Englisch lernen soll, um Fragen und Antworten zu verstehen. Wenn wir ständig auf Englisch konferieren werden sich natürlich die, die sehr schwach sind in Englisch, abwenden. D.h. die Quote, die Du beobachtest, wird durch das von Dir propagierte Verhalten vielleicht erst erzeugt.

Comment: Whenever I see or am part of a group of mixed nationalities the common language is English.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: Wir sind aber nicht irgendeine, international zusammengewürfelte Gruppe. Es geht hier um die dt. Sprache.